# Why can't I run my images on QEMU? (Infinite Loop at VM boot)

Tags: 14.04, android, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I've installed QEMU/KVM, and I'm trying to create a Virtual Machine running Android using a .iso obtained from the Android-x86 project.

I can run the .iso using `-cdrom <address>/android-x86_64-7.1-r2.iso -boot d` and the installation is accused of being successful, 10G partitioned as one bootable ext4. However, when I reboot, the QEMU reads the .img and recognizes it as an Android, but then it takes me to a black screen/blank screen.

If I opt for a Debug run, when it gets to that part, it shows me an infinite loop. Many services like `'zygote_secundary'`, `'cameraserver'`, and others are getting `killed by Signal 6` or `Signal 9`, or just killed, then restarted.
It also starts accusing `SELinux` of not being defined.

I did it with different ISOs, Android 8.1 to Android 6.0, and the result is the same:
I can run enough to install them, but I can't run enough to boot the android system, any of them.

Commands entered:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-bin
$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 android-test.img 10G
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -net nic -net user -hda android-test.img -cdrom android-x86_64-7.1-r2.iso -boot d
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -net nic -net user -hda android-test.img
```

I don't know how to copy the QEMU logs though, so if you need specific information and can guide me on how to get it for you, I'll do it.

Edit:

---

1.
Ran a `kvm-ok` test:

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Comment: I once had Oracle VM VIrtualBox installed here, but it was uninstalled long ago, and I don't know if maybe something was left messed up, like, some library maybe?